# Calibration of LCD display type thermometer (without extended probes)

Tags: instrument

How can we ensure correctness of an LCD display type thermometer used indoor e.g. the HTC-1 which does not have extended probes.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have an HTC-1, and I checked it by putting a lab thermometer on the table top next to it. To avoid conduction from the table I balanced the lab thermometer on a piece of insulating foam with the bulb positioned freely in the air.

Since this was in winter I could measure a range of temperatures from first thing in the morning when it was flipping cold to lunchtime when the central heating had done its work. Somewhat to my surprise (the HTC-1 is a very cheap thermometer!) I found the HTC-1 was within a degree of the lab thermometer over a range of 10ºC to 25ºC.

Comment: thanks John, even i have compared the readings of HTC-1 with another thermometer/altimeter and readings are withing 2-3deg apart. But i wish to know how to caliberate this device.